# Создание сертификатов/бланков

Tags: php

Есть ли какая-то техника печати бланков/сертификатов на php c возможностью вывода их на печать в дальнейшем ? Т.е. к примеру у нас есть пустая заготовка(бланка/сертификата), пользователеь вводит свои данные в форме, php все это расставляет по определенным позициям, в зависимости от заготовки, и отдает готовый бланк/сертификат с данными которые ранее ввел пользователь, как-то так.

Типа такого нужно [simplecertificate](https://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_simplecertificate), может кто подскажет готовое решение ?

Comment: Не обязательно php, возможно js или еще чего-то, просто нужно потом сохранить все это в jpg к примеру, а его уже на печать. Перерыл весь гугл, но он выдает ссылки только на получение сертификата...

Comment: так искать надо не сертификаты, а печать страницы (произвольной), а саму страницу вы уже оформляете когда с печатью разобрались. Еще вариант - генерировать pdf (или любой другой документ, например word), т.е. саму распечатку на пользователя оставить, а ему предоставлять макет для печати

Comment: Дайте ссылку на пример пожалуйста, по-моему это то что мне нужно, просто не знаю как правильно у гугла спросить :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен именно PHP, то я бы посоветовал генерировать PDF с нужной информацией.
Очень советую PHP класс TCPDF (www.tcpdf.org) - довольно мощная штука для создания PDF файлов из php.

Делается форма, в которой собирается вся необходимая информация. Форма отправляется в php скрипт, который и создает PDF. Если у Вас серктификат с навороченной графикой, то саму графику можно фоновой картинкой поставить...
Еще, Вам может пригодиться, класс позволяет заблокировать PDF от редактуры, добавить мета, комменты и т.д....

Вобщем мощная штука. Там на сайте много примеров. Сам пользуюсь.
Поначалу может придется повозиться...